# Are there any names for this (JavaScript property accessor) notation?

Tags: javascript

```
var A0003 = object['some key']['some other key'];
```

with regards to the square brackets??

---

where A0003 is accessing:

```
var object = {
   'some key': {
      'some other key': 'data'
   }
}
```

Comment: It is called as bracket notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is called bracket notation. It's one of two ways to access properties in JS. The other being dot notation. However in your case, since you have whitespace in your property name only bracket notation will work. 
See [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Bracket notation:

```
object[property_name];
```

Dot notation:

```
object.property_name;
```